# How to remove empty values from multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, string, multidimensional-array, filtering, isnullorempty

I've been looking a lot of answers, but none of them are working for me.

This is the data assigned to my `$quantities` array:

```
Array(
    [10] => Array([25.00] => 1)
    [9] => Array([30.00] => 3)
    [8] => Array([30.00] => 4)
    [12] => Array([35.00] => )
    [1] => Array([30.00] => )
    [2] => Array([30.00] => )
)
```

I'm looking for a way to remove the subarrays with empty values like `[12]` `[1]` and `[2]` while keeping everything else.

The desired result:

```
Array(
    [10] => Array([25.00] => 1)
    [9] => Array([30.00] => 3)
    [8] => Array([30.00] => 4)
)
```

I tried a lot of the functions on the official php docs and none of them worked.

I've used this one:

```
function array_filter_recursive($array, $callback = null) {
    foreach ($array as $key => & $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = array_filter_recursive($value, $callback);
        } else {
            if ( ! is_null($callback)) {
                if ( ! $callback($value)) {
                    unset($array[$key]);
                }
            } else {
                if ( ! (bool) $value) {
                    unset($array[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    unset($value);
    return $array;
}
```

But it only removes the element in the subarrays; I need the subarrays to be removed entirely.

I don't want this:

```
Array(
    [10] => Array([25.00] => 1)
    [9] => Array([30.00] => 3)
    [8] => Array([30.00] => 4)
    [12] => Array()
    [1] => Array()
    [2] => Array()
)
```

Comment: Consider using var_dump() instead to show us the array contents.

Comment: For a page that is used as a destination for so many dupe links, this page has an amazing amount of upvoted incorrect answers.  @Richard-MX I have posted an answer that doesn't use recursion or multiple iterating functions so that readers that are trafficked here are able to see a lean working (zero-safe) solution. (it is unclear in your post if your empty arrays have empty strings or `null` as values, so I demo'ed with both)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Bit late, but may help someone looking for same answer. I used this very simple approach to;

1. remove all the keys from nested arrays that contain no value, then
2. remove all the empty nested arrays.

---

```
$postArr = array_map('array_filter', $postArr);
$postArr = array_filter( $postArr );
```

Answer (score 6):

The following function worked for my case. We can use a simple recursive function to remove all empty elements from the multidimensional PHP array:

```
function array_filter_recursive($input){
    foreach ($input as &$value){
        if (is_array($value)){
            $value = array_filter_recursive($value);
        }
    }
    return array_filter($input);
}
```

Then we just need to call this function:

```
$myArray = array_filter_recursive($myArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly what your looking for.

```
function array_remove_null($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_null($value))
            unset($array[$key]);
        if(is_array($value))
            $array[$key] = array_remove_null($value);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

> Update (corrections):

```
function array_remove_null($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_null($value))
            unset($array[$key]);
        if(is_string($value) && empty($value))
            unset($array[$key]);
        if(is_array($value))
            $array[$key] = array_remove_null($value);
        if(isset($array[$key]) && count($array[$key])==0)
            unset($array[$key]);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

I'm sure better checking and making this more robust might help the solution.

Comment: Hello Jason, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for what i need. As Paul answer, it returns the same as the original question.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has 4 upvotes.  This code-only answer does not work.  [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a06f86d99043713158cb6170b516ffebd9533f4a)

Comment: @mickmackusa this example worked back in the days of PHP 5.

Comment: @JasonFoglia There is nothing version specific that is impacting your answer.  It doesn't work in php5 either. [PHP 5.5.0.a.2 Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a570d9598a8c366ad3864fa9884f42f1a17af76)

Comment: @mickmackusa This answer answers the question. How to remove VALUES from an array; not empty arrays from arrays.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156933/discussion-between-jason-foglia-and-mickmackusa).

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_filter` with `array_map` like below:

```
$arr=array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $arr));
```

Comment: This is not new information.  This is a duplicate of [AlastairF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796083/2943403) written as a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

use array_map() for filter every array in $array:

```
$newArray = array_map('array_filter', $array);
```

Here's [demo](http://codepad.org/xpSUedId)

Comment: This answer DOESN'T WORK.  It doesn't work in the posted demo link.  It doesn't work in [my demo link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8b7659f6b504afea691451351c039de24c0a7f4)  How in the world did this earn 3 upvotes?  Downvote from me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array_map('array_filter', $array);
```

This sintax it's work and very help full thank's guys ..

Comment: This is an exact duplicate method (character for character) of NaitikShah's answer that was posted two months earlier.  If you cannot improve your answer to provide better information you should delete this answer because it does not add value to the page (it is merely page bloat).

Comment: This answer DOESN'T WORK.  It doesn't work in [my demo link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8b7659f6b504afea691451351c039de24c0a7f4)  How in the world did this earn 3 upvotes?  Downvote from me.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
function array_filter_recursive($input){
    foreach ($input as &$value){
        if (is_array($value)){
            $value = array_filter_recursive($value);
        }
    }
    return array_filter($input);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This removes all items with null values recursively on multideminsional arrays. Works on PHP >= 5.6. If you want to remove all "empty" values, replace `!is_null($value)` with `!empty($value)`.

```
function recursivelyRemoveItemsWithNullValuesFromArray(array $data = []): array
{
    $data = array_map(function($value) {
        return is_array($value) ? recursivelyRemoveItemsWithNullValuesFromArray($value) : $value;
    }, $data);

    return array_filter($data, function($value) {
        return !is_null($value);
    });
}
```

Comment: This answer does not provide the OP's desired output.  [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c30daafe3cf0959e0a0c4dcaa901244605a8f7d9)

Comment: @mickmackusa As stated in my answer "If you want to remove all "empty" values, replace !is_null($value) with !empty($value)". You Demo works as expected. I updated your demo using empty() instead of is_null(). Please check: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf91c085d8ed75da7854d1e4814495d06cc1fa04

Answer (score -4):

Because the subarrays in your array only have one element each, you can simplify the approach using either of the two following methods.  The logical advantage is in avoiding the functional iterator (`array_filter`) on the second level elements.  This is why `current()` is more suitable for this question/page.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29b138c53461b96589ebf3b2fda71e721f247b53))

```
$quantities=[
    10=>['25.00'=>1],
    9=>['30.00'=>3],
    8=>['30.00'=>4],
    12=>['35.00'=>null],
    1=>['30.00'=>''],
    2=>['30.00'=>null]
];

var_export(array_filter($quantities,function($a){return strlen(current($a));}));
```

OR

```
foreach($quantities as $key=>$sub){  // could be done "by reference" but that impacts code stability
    if(!strlen(current($sub))){  // if subarray value has no length
        unset($quantities[$key]);
    }
}
var_export($quantities);
```

Both output the same result (which purposely removes empty values and preserves `0` values)

```
array (
  10 => 
  array (
    '25.00' => 1,
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    '30.00' => 3,
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    '30.00' => 4,
  ),
)
```

In the above methods, `strlen()` is used to check the 2nd level elements because the OP only listed integers as the "non-empty" values.  Future SO readers may have different requirements based on the elements possibly holding `false`, `null`, `'0'`, `0`, etc.  Suitable replacement functions for `strlen()` may be: any of [the "is_" functions](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=is&scope=quickref), [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), any of [the "ctype" functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php), and many more.

If the OP's 2nd level array held more than one element AND the OP wanted to remove all zero-ish, false-y, empty, null elements (meaning zeros are not wanted or guaranteed not to occur), then [Alastair F's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796083/2943403) would be the best choice.

If the OP's input array had an unknown number of levels AND zero-ish/false-y/empty/null elements should be removed, then [Reza Mamun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32382871/2943403) is a logical, recursive approach.

My point being (and my motivation behind spending so much time and care to answer this question) that `array_filter()` is greedy and if you aren't aware of this default behavior, your project may silently output incorrect information.  I hope this explanation saves programmers some time and strife.