# How can i remove empty array from multidimenssional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array in which several child arrays exists. I want to remove those arrays which specifics values are empty.

```
Array ( 
[9] => Array ( [address_id] => 9 [firstname] => [lastname] =>  ) 
[10] => Array ( [address_id] => 10 [firstname] => the [lastname] => king  ) 
[11] => Array ( [address_id] => 11 [firstname] => the [lastname] => queen  ) 
)
```

You can see `firstname` and `lastname` is empty in `[9] => Array()`. So how can i remove those arrays which `firstname` has blank? I have tried array_filter() but didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Try using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and recursively unset the cells which have an empty lastname or firstname ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove empty values from multidimensional array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214531/how-to-remove-empty-values-from-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `array_filter()` with an anonymous function:

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($v) { return !empty($v['firstname']); });
```

For firstname AND lastname:

```
$array = array_filter($array,
                      function($v) {
                        return !empty($v['firstname']) && !empty($v['lastname']);
                      });
```

Keep in mind `empty()` is also `0`, `false` and `null`, so for just an empty string you might want `return $v['firstname'] !== '';` or something similar.

Comment: what about `lastname`?

Comment: I don't know OP said _"So how can i remove those arrays which firstname has blank?"_

Answer (score 0):

Assuming parent array is named `$parent`, you want to loop through and check conditionally for two empty fields, then unset indexes that match.

```
foreach ($parent as $key -> $value){
    if ($value['lastname'] == "" AND $value['firstname'] == ""){
        // Names not set, remove from parent array
        unset($parent[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove all the keys from nested arrays that contain no value, then remove all the empty nested arrays.

```
$postArr = array_map('array_filter', $postArr);
$postArr = array_filter( $postArr );
```