# I need to use a foreach loop on a json in php, but i only want to return unique values

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, unique-array

I have parsed and decoded a json into a php file. The json is in a format similar to this:

```
{"name":"John Doe", "records":[{"sample": "sample","fields":{"date":"Sample Date","Sample Field":"Sample value", "id": "sampleid"}}
```

I have a lot of records that are similar to this in that file.  I have been using a `foreach` loop to return all of the `date` fields.  The loop looks something like:

```
$records = $records_json['records'];
foreach($records as $record) {
        echo "<option>" . $record['fields']['date'] . "</option>";
}
```

Right now, this is returning all of the dates.  However, there are a lot of duplicate dates, and I only want to return the unique dates (without duplicates).  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you add some more records with duplicate `date` to your example json structure?

Comment: this link is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214531/how-to-remove-empty-values-from-multidimensional-array-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array where you store the dates and check the new dates against the values in this array to see if the "new" date is in there, if it isn't it is a unique date and should be added to the array.

```
$records = $records_json['records'];
$uniques = array():
foreach($records as $record) {
    if (!in_array($record['fields']['date'], $uniques)) {
        $uniques[] = $record['fields']['date'];
    }
}
foreach ($uniques as $unique) {
    echo "<option>" . $unique . "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<?php
$records_json = '{"name":"John Doe", "records":[{"sample": "sample","fields":{"date":"Sample Date","Sample Field":"Sample value", "id": "sampleid"}}]}';
$arr = json_decode($records_json,TRUE);
$records = $arr['records'];
foreach($records as $record) {
        echo  $record['fields']['date'] ;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo online](https://eval.in/599206)**

```
 <?php

$json = '{"name":"John Doe", "records":[{"sample": "sample","fields":{"date":"Sample Date","Sample Field":"Sample value", "id": "sampleid"}}]}';

$json  = json_decode($json , true);
$dates = [];

foreach($json['records'] as $record) {
   $date = $record['fields']['date'];
   if(!isset($dates[$date]))
      $dates[]= $date;
}

var_dump($dates);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can build a date array and then filter it with [array_unique](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

```
<?php

$array  = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
$unique = array_unique($array);

var_export($unique);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'foo',
  2 => 'bar',
  3 => 'baz',
)
```

Comment: array is multidimensional

Comment: That's why I suggest in the answer to build an array of dates before using array_unique.